# Backbonejs if URL is not equal to defined route

Tags: backbone.js, routes

How do I validate URLs in backbone if it's not equal to my defined route?

ex. 
    `if (url !== certain route) {
        // do stuff here
    }`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an all-inclusive splat as the last route in your Route

```
routes: {
  ...
  '*default' : 'default'
}
```

Then

```
default: function(route) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps